# Python - skip if has not pattern of date

Tags: python, date, csv, pattern-matching

I have a csv where I have for example this:

```
Date,Comment

2014-05-29,Last time we will see

What about next time?"

2014-05-29,"""still want to be seen as the good guys..."""

This is my world. 

2014-05-29,And so the game begins... ;)

2014-05-29,"Btw, this is...
```

And I would like to skip those rows which have not a date format in first column. I have this:

```
a = []
csvReader = csv.reader(open(csv_file_to_open, 'rb'), delimiter=',')
for row in csvReader:
    a.append(row)

for row in a:
    if row[0] == "date format then": <= here I need some pattern filter but I don't know how to do it
        print 'yes'
```

Date is always in format `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: You can always choose to edit the comment before posting it in your question.

Comment: You should look into regular expressions for this - I find http://regex101.com/#python useful for that

Comment: I'm new with regex, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Nowhere in the question do you mention regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the datetime module to check this:

```
import datetime
a = []
csvReader = csv.reader(open(csv_file_to_open, 'rb'), delimiter=',')
for row in csvReader:
    a.append(row)

for row in a:
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],'%Y-%m-%d')
        print 'yes'
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

This should do it!

Comment: would be great, but `except:` should not be suggested... You should ALWAYS catch only specific errors, in this case: `except ValueError:`